# PSQL Recursive Adding Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called "deaths" with two columns. One is a date, and the second is the amount of people who died on that specific date.
I need a query that gives me the total amount of people who died between that date and 90 days prior. For example, if row value of the date is 30/09/2021, I would need to add the deaths since 02/07/2021.
¿Can I get any guidance as to how can I do this?
"deaths" Table example below.

```
    Date    | Deaths | 
------------+--------+
 2021-08-19 |     21 |
 2021-08-18 |     96 |
 2021-08-17 |    100 |
 2021-08-16 |     64 |
 2021-08-15 |    107 |
 2021-08-14 |     93 |
```

So, if this was all my data, the first row (2021-08-19) of my result should be (21 + 96 + 100 + 64 + 107 + 93).

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Note; `date` is a bad name for a column. (did you see the syntax-highlighting?)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for noting this. I changed it just for sake of it being more understandable, the real name of the column is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a recursive query for this, you can use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) instead.  As others have mentioned, "date" is not a good name for a column and it would have been better to give sample data with dates more than 90 days apart, but I believe this query should work for you:

```
SELECT "date",
       deaths,
       sum(deaths) OVER (ORDER BY "date" RANGE BETWEEN interval '90 days' preceding and current row)
FROM deaths;
```

The clause `RANGE BETWEEN interval '90 days' preceding and current row`, called the frame, limits the rows that will be part of the sum.

Comment: Great solution. PostgreSQL is one of the few engines that implement time ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Select distinct "date" , (Select sum(deaths) from table where 
 "date" <=d."date" and "date" >=d."date" -90)
   as tot_deaths from tabl3 d;
```

Comment: Hey, with a bit of reformatting, I tried what you told me. Here it is:

`SELECT DISTINCT "date", 
(SELECT SUM(deaths) FROM deaths WHERE 
"date" <= deaths."date" AND "date" >= deaths."date" - INTERVAL '90 day')
AS tot_deaths FROM deaths;
`

But the result I get is just the sum of all the historic deaths, repeated for each date. It is not considering the 90 days. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Also, the subquery gives me as a result a table with only one row and one column, containing the total amount of deaths in the table. as in: sum = 109, even having very different dates. In my table I have deaths from 2013 and from 2021.